# Query to get average of multiple columns and rows

Tags: sql, select, average

My table data is like below

```
id    a      b      c      d
101    2      2      2      2
101    3      3      3      3
101    2      2      2      2
102    5      5      5      5
102    5      5      5      5
```

and I want output as per id and average of all concern rows and columns
for example

```
id     average
101    2.33
102    5
```

Comment: Not sure what DBMS you're using, but if you're only looking at a fixed number of columns just use `(a+b+c+d)/4`, a `GROUP BY` and a `SUM` (sorry, hit enter too soon).

Comment: Use Avg() aggregate function and by looks of your table use the DISTICT modifier

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
select id, avg((a+b+c+d)/4) from table_name group by id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Average is the sum of the items divided by their count. The nice thing about these two mathematical functions is that they are cumulative, so:

```
SELECT   id, SUM (a + b + c + d) / (COUNT(*) * 4) -- There are four columns
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY id
```